# automatic reload sketches in processing

Tags: processing, processing-ide

I'd like to be more efficient with processing programming, is there a way to run a sketch from the command line? maybe also with a watch for file saves?

Also, is there some autocompletion for processing? the default IDE is very limited..

Comment: why do you want to run a sketch from the command line?  and what exactly do you mean by "watch for file saves"?  re: autocompletion, nope.  if you want better IDE features, you should consider migrating your workflow to eclipse.  look into proclipsing for help with this.

Comment: @ericsoco - I personally would have to run from the command line, because ["Use external editor" is gone in beta 5. Now what? - Processing Forum](http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/use-external-editor-is-gone-in-beta-5-now-what.html); so now if you: have a .pde open in Processing; edit a .pde in external editor and save; and click Run back in Processing - Processing will **not** see the new changes, and will run the old .pde; so you'd have to re-open it (including entering the right path) in the IDE, which isn't exactly convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @erisoco mentions, using the Eclipse IDE is your best bet (especially for autocomplete/etc.) and the [Proclipsing plugin](http://code.google.com/p/proclipsing/) makes it very easy to setup Processing projects in eclipse (including integration with external libraries)

[image: Proclipsing]

There's also a quick [video tutorial](http://vimeo.com/19076476) on setup if necessary.

You mentioned "watch for file saves" - that sounds along the lines of "live coding".
There are multiple options. One I've used in the past is through the [FluidForms library](http://code.google.com/p/fluid-forms-libs/). The library also includes some handy features for (3D) design (like parameter changer, automatic arcball for 3D scenes, STL export, etc.)
You can find a few quick video tutorials on live coding Processing with Fluid Forms libs:

1. [Fluid-Forms-Libs ~ HelloWorld](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4E0l-skibw&list=UU0a5jTXOlTFd3KuwGiGoVOA&index=8&feature=plcp)
2. [Fluid Forms Libs Parameter Changer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWqAhca_77E&list=UU0a5jTXOlTFd3KuwGiGoVOA&index=5&feature=plcp)
3. [FluidFormsLibs-LiveCoding](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DzOZSMUwZjU&list=UU0a5jTXOlTFd3KuwGiGoVOA&index=4&feature=plcp)

[image: fluidforms hello world]
[image: fluidforms param changer]
[image: fluidforms live coding]

Comment: if I'm not mistaken that FluidForm is pretty old and doesn't work with processing 2, right?

Comment: I've just tested with the 2.0b3 core.jar and you're right, I've running into errors with a basic P3D sketch (with no FluidForms): `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT (8cd6)`. If you want to use FluidForms I'd say stick to Processing 1.5.1 for now.

Answer (score 2):

### Windows and Linux

Pretty much the same when you want to run the sketch from the command line.

Within your processing folder there should be a *processing-java* file. If you cd to it's folder, you can use

```
./processing-java --help
```

Which will show you the required parameters to running, compiling and whatnot.

---

**If you are in a hurry**, this would do (replace the *$parameters* with the folders you want or automate it with your editor):

```
$PROCESSING_DIR/processing-java --sketch=$CURRENT_DOCUMENT_DIR --output=$CURRENT_DOCUMENT_DIR/run --run --force
```

This is my Gedit script:

```
/home/otto/GameDev/processing-2.1/processing-java --sketch=$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_DIR  --output=$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_DIR/run --run --force
```

---

### MacOSX

Haven't had a chance to test it but it shouldn't be any harder.

---

Source: http://wiki.processing.org/w/Command_Line

Answer (score 0):

This is the command I use:

```
> processing-java --sketch=R:\sketch_folder --force --run
```

I do the coding using Visual Studio Code https://code.visualstudio.com/ with the processing extension.